# I would like to know how to not reinstall the app every time you start a new test

Tags: python, mobile, automated-tests, pytest, appium

I'm performing E2E mobile tests with Appium and Pytest. I would like to know how to not reinstall the app every time you start a new test. I already tried using noReset and it didn't solve my problem. I've also tried using the scope='class' in the driver setup in the conftest, but if I put that in, the tests that run after the first test break, because they stay on the first test screen and don't go to the second screen.

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make sure to reuse the driver in every test. The initialisation of the driver (which will happen in the first test) should take care of the app install. Take a look at noReset and fullReset, see [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html) for the specifics, you might need to use both?

Then after every test, make sure to get to the preferred state for the next test. Perhaps you want to be logged out? Then make sure to end every test with a logout. Etc... I'm not clear to what you mean with first test screen and second screen, so feel free to elaborate with more specifics if you want a more specific answer.